Transform S-JTK coordinates to WGS84 ProjNet
double x = 1114492.28;
double y = 544711.47;

double[] xy = { x, y };

var cf = new CoordinateSystemFactory();
var f = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();
string wkt25831 = "PROJCS[\"S-JTSK / Krovak East North\",GEOGCS[\"S-JTSK\",DATUM[\"System_Jednotne_Trigonometricke_Site_Katastralni\",SPHEROID[\"Bessel 1841\",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7004\"]],TOWGS84[570.8,85.7,462.8,4.998,1.587,5.261,3.56],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6156\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4156\"]],PROJECTION[\"Krovak\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center\",49.5],PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\",24.83333333333333],PARAMETER[\"azimuth\",30.28813972222222],PARAMETER[\"pseudo_standard_parallel_1\",78.5],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9999],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"X\",EAST],AXIS[\"Y\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"5514\"]]";

string wkt3857 = "PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / World Mercator\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],PROJECTION[\"Mercator_1SP\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",0],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",1],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3395\"]]";

var sys25831 = cf.CreateFromWkt(wkt25831);
var sys3857 = cf.CreateFromWkt(wkt3857);

var transformTo3857 = f.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(sys25831, sys3857);

double[] ret = transformTo3857.MathTransform.Transform(xy);

var xnew = ret[0];
var ynew = ret[1];
Console.WriteLine($"X: {xnew}\nY: {ynew}");

Expected result:
X: 49.658437102190874
Y: 17.275185540951714
getting:
X: 5199947,284703191
Y: 9148290,341105413
How to get correct result from S-JTSK into GPS WGS84 coordinates (not UTM)?
Using ProjNet Nuget package
